# Why the bmp image that my program creates does not open?

Tags: java, fileinputstream, bmp, fileoutputstream, steganography

My steganography program takes a string and a bmp image from the user and creates a new bmp image of the same photo but slightly altered to hide the string in the LSB of each byte in the image.

However, when I write the bmp image it does not open. When I just read the bytes and write them back it opens okay, but not when I alter the LSB of few of its bytes it does not. I can see from testing the code that the value of bytes are either not changed or changed by one (for ex 72 instead of 73) but that causes the image not to open for some reason. This is the code in question.

```
   public String hideString(String payload, String cover_filename) throws IOException
{

/**reads source image*/
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cover_filename);

/**reads how many bytes are in the image*/
int size = fis.available();

/**loops through all bytes in the bmp image and saves them in List list*/
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    list.add(fis.read());
}

fis.close();



/**turns payload into an array of integers - each integer is either 0 or 1*/
int[] binValues = toBinary(payload);


/**loops though payload and hides it in each byte*/
for(int i = 0; i < binValues.length; i++)
    {
        /**swapLsb takes 1 or 0 from payload and puts it in Lsb in each image byte and returns a binary integer of various sizes(no leading zeros)*/
        String s = "" + swapLsb(binValues[i], list.get(i));


        /**converts binary integer into an integer and adds it to List listAltered*/
        listAltered.add(Integer.parseInt(s, 2));
    }

/**writes stego image*/
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("stego.bmp");

/**writes altered bytes into the bmp image*/
for(int i = 0; i < binValues.length; i++)
    {fos.write(listAltered.get(i));count++;}

/**writes the rest of bytes into bmp image*/
for(int i = binValues.length; i < size; i++)
fos.write(list.get(i));

fos.close();//close writing object

return "Success! new image is called 'stego.bmp'";

}
```

Comment: solved, if you face the same issue, don't alter the first 54 bytes in a windows bmp file as they're used for head information. :D

Comment: The `available()` method only returns how many bytes can be read without blocking.  It does *not* return the total number of bytes in the stream.  From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--): “It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.”